# Бесконечный запрос ввода при вызове open()

Tags: c++, linux

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int fd;
    size_t size;
    char name[]="aaa.fifо";
    umask(0) ;// Обнуляем маску создания файлов текущего процесса для того, чтобы права доступа у создаваемого FIFO точно соответствовали параметру вызова mknod()
    // Попытаемся создать FIFO с именем aaa.fifo в текущей директории
    if (mknod(name, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0) < 0){ 
        // Если создать FIFO не удалось, печатаем об этом сообщение и прекращаем работу 
        printf("Can\'t create FIFO\n");
        _exit(-1);
    }
    if ((fd = open(name, O_WRONLY)) < 0){ // открывает aaa.fifo
        //  Если открыть FIFO не удалось, печатаем об этом сообщение и рекращаем работу 
        printf("Can\'t open FIFO for writing\n");
        _exit(-1);
    }
    char message[60];
    while(true){
        message[0] = 0;
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin >> message;// читаем сообщения из консоли
        if(!strcmp(message,"exit")) // если обнаружен,exit выходим из цикла
        {
            printf("Exit to programm\n");
            break;
        }
        size = write(fd, message, 60); // 1 - это /0
        if (size < strlen(message)) { // Если записалось меньшее количество байт, то сообщаем об ошибке и завершаем работу
            printf("Can\'t write all string to FIFO\n");
            _exit(-1);
        }
    }
    close(fd);// Закрываем поток 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Путем тыка понял, что проблема возникает при вызове open() ЧО ДЕЛАТЬ ТО ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема в том что при вводе exit он не завершает цикл. После дебага принтом, я понял что даже в начале мейна добавить printf или cout ничего не выводит а просто ждет инпут. до цикла запрос инпута, а где не понятно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Файл типа FIFO это точка рандеву, в которой образуется канал, а вовсе не емкость, куда одни могут лить, а другие оттуда черпать.

Т.е. одна программа (процесс), должна открывать его на запись, **а другая** на чтение. Пока визави не откроет файл, первая программы будет ожидать на вызове `open()`.

После того, как вторая программа вызвала `open` обе продолжат выполнение и смогут посылать-получать данные.

Кстати, добавьте к вызову `mknod` проверку, что файл уже существует. Например, вот так:

```
if (mknod(name, S_IFIFO | 0666, 0) < 0 && errno != EEXIST){ 
    // Если создать FIFO не удалось, печатаем об этом сообщение и прекращаем работу 
    printf("Can\'t create FIFO %m\n");
    _exit(-1);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное за великолепный ответ♥